Rust function that returns a value inside a Mutex<Option<T>>
I have a bunch of functions in my rust app that all get a Mutex as a parameter, which holds an Option. I need that Mutex because the functions will be executed in threads, and I need the Option because the value is not set in the beginning and has to be initialized at some point in runtime.
Now, all those functions begin with extracting that value, like this:
fn do_something(state_mutex: Mutex<Option<MyDataStruct>>) -> Result<(), MyCustomError> {
  let state_option = state_mutex.lock()?;
  let state = state_option.as_mut().ok_or(MyCustomError::new("value was None"))?;

  // rest of the function...
}

Now, to keep it DRY, how could I put that lines of code into a single function, like this:
fn do_something(state_mutex: Mutex<Option<MyDataStruct>>) -> Result<(), MyCustomError> {
  let state = get_state_from_mutex(&mut state_mutex);

  // rest of the function...
}

I have no idea how to write that get_state_from_mutex function.
The cleanest way I found to do that was the following:
fn get_state_from_mutex(state_mutex: &mut Mutex<Option<MyDataStruct>>) -> Result<&mut MyDataStruct, MyCustomError>
  Ok(&mut state_mutex
    .get_mut()?
    .ok_or(MyCustomError::new("value was None"))?
  )
}

But this fails with
cannot return value referencing temporary value
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

So how can I give the ownership of that temporary value to my do_something function? Or is there a better approach to do this?
I'd also be fine using macros, but I feel like it should be possible creating a function for this.
Thank you
Edit:
Here the error message from cargo / rustc:
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
 --> src/commands.rs:8:2
  |
8 |     Ok(&mut state_mutex.get_mut()?.ok_or(MyCustomError::new("value was None"))?)
  |     ^^^^^^^^-------------------------------------------------------------------^
  |     |       |
  |     |       temporary value created here
  |     returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0507]: cannot move out of a mutable reference
 --> src/commands.rs:8:10
  |
8 |     Ok(&mut state_mutex.get_mut()?.ok_or(MyCustomError::new("value was None"))?)
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `std::option::Option<MyDataStruct>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait


Please post the full error from cargo check, not your IDE.

Do you really have mutable access to or full ownership of the Mutex? That is not commonly the case.

Also consider OnceLock

@kmdreko Yes, I have full ownership of the Mutex, but I tested it if get_state_from_mutex gets an owned Mutex as an argument instead of a borrowed one. But that didn't work, and it also makes less sense to me bc if I understood it correctly, Mutex.lock() lasts until it goes out of scope, and that would be when get_state_from_mutex returns.

Remove the &mut and add as_mut() if necessary.

@ChayimFriedman Ok, I tried a bit, and this worked for me

@ChayimFriedman ok update, it worked like in the reproducable example, but it seems like there's another problem because actually, the Mutex<Option<MyDataStruct>> is behind a tauri State, and I now get the error cannot borrow data in dereference of "State<'_, AppData>" as mutable

Well, then you don't have &mut Mutex, you have &Mutex as usual. You can't extract &mut T from this.

The problem with returning a bare reference is that a guard must exist to protect the access (and release the lock when dropped). See How to return a reference to a sub-value of a value that is under a mutex? Though its not clear how that'd look if you want to short-circuit if the Option is None.

Ok... as that seems to get very complicated, is there a way to achieve the same thing with a macro? Because when I tried it, it failed because I was creatint a temporary value or so...

Thanks to everyone who commented. I wasn't able to solve the problem in the way I wanted, but I found a workaround that works for me.
The main problem seems to be that, after locking the Mutex, I get a value of type MutexGuard<Option<MyDataStruct>>. I want to convert it to MyDataStruct, but it seems like it's difficult to extract a value from a MutexGuard. I'd need to find a way to convert from MutexGuard<Option<T>> to MutexGuard<T>, but that doesn't seem to be possible, so I decided to just keep the MutexGuard as it is and hold it in a struct like this:
struct GuardedData<'a> (MutexGuard<'a, Option<MyDataStruct>>);

Now, if I want to use that MyDataStruct somewhere in a function, I need to unwrap the Option in that function, because if I'd write an external function for unwrapping it, that temporary value would live only in that external function and couldn't be returned (if I understood it correctly).
So I'd have to always handle the None case in every function I use that data struct. To avoid that, I check for a None value only when the GuardedData struct is created, and when using it later in a function, I'll only have to call .unwrap() on it.
I know that's technnically not the best solution and theoretically the program could panic, but I think it won't because when the constructor ensures that the value is Some and not None, it will stay like this until the original Mutex is dropped (meaning until the function returns), because while the Mutex is locked noone can mutate the underlying data.
impl<'a> GuardedData<'a> {
  fn from_guard(guard: MutexGuard<'a, Option<MyDataStruct>>) -> Result<Self, MyCustomError> {
    match *guard {
      Some(_) => Ok(Self(guard)),
      None => Err(MyCustomError::new("value was None")
    }
  }

  fn get_inner(&mut self) -> Option<&mut MyDataStruct> {
    self.0.as_mut()
  }
}

I then wrote a function to construct a GuardedData from a Mutex and handle errors:
fn get_guarded_data(mx: &Mutex<Option<MyDataStruct>>) -> Result<GuardedData, MyCustomError> {
  DbGuard::from_opt(mx.lock().some_error_handling(...)?)
}

And now, I can use it in any function I want like this:
fn do_something(state: Mutex<Option<MyDataStruct>>) -> Result<(), MyCustomError> {
  let mut data = get_guarded_data(&state)?;

  do_some_other_stuff(data.get_inner().unwrap());
}

fn do_some_other_stuff(data_ref: &mut MyDataStruct) {
  // ...
}

This solution might not be ideal for everyone, so I won't mark this answer as accepted yet, because maybe someone has a better idea. Maybe you can also tell me your thoughts about this solution.
